# I am having issues with a row name having a .z in it. (Will not allow to be plotted)

Tags: r

I am trying to throw some ID numbers on some data recovered from an online data center. In my code I am attempting to organize the data into decades (groups of ten years). To do this I am creating a dummy row call: "OBS".

When I attach the OBS to the DF (SB$OBS <- rbind(z)) The row shows up with a .z as in "OBS.z".

This will not allow me to create a boxplot (boxplot(SB$Value~SB$OBS).

It throws the error: (Error in stats::model.frame.default(formula = SB$Value ~ SB$OBS) : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'SB$OBS')

I've tried everything and I'm sure its something easy that I am missing.

```
library(devtools)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(rnassqs)

# Via CRAN
install_github('potterzot/rnassqs')

pdf("/DesktopFigures/Agriculture/corn_pawnee.pdf")

####################### STARTS WITH CORN ###############
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
params = list(commodity_desc = "CORN", #crop for data wanted
        year = NULL, #choses year, NULL = all available years
        state_name = "IOWA", #State wanted
        agg_level_desc = "COUNTY", # breaks the data into per county 
        county_name = "SHELBY", #selects for wanted county
        prodn_practice_desc = "ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES") # this is the irrigation and non together.Can be seperated by changing this

SB <- nassqs_area(params, area = "AREA PLANTED") #area calls for area planted, this too can be changes (i.e. area harvested..)

#####Value data (acres) imports have characters, We must convert to numbers with this######
SB$Value <- gsub(",","",SB$Value)
SB$Value <- as.numeric(as.character(SB$Value))

####number of box plots###
n <- count(SB) 
gg <- n/10

g_g <- round(gg, digits = 2)

#############box plot for data ############
# n..... /10 =  gg#  box plots

z <- rep(1:(nrow(SB)/10),10)
print(z <- sort(z, decreasing = TRUE))
z <- data.frame(z)
nnm  <- (nrow(SB)-nrow(z))
z[nrow(z) + nnm,] = c(1)
z[is.na(z)] <- 1

SB$OBS <- rbind(z)

boxplot(SB$Value~SB$OBS)
```

It throws the error: (Error in stats::model.frame.default(formula = SB$Value ~ SB$OBS) : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'SB$OBS')

```
    str(SB)
    'data.frame':   93 obs. of  40 variables:
     $ country_name         : chr  "UNITED STATES" "UNITED STATES" "UNITED STATES" "UNITED STATES" ...
     $ agg_level_desc       : chr  "COUNTY" "COUNTY" "COUNTY" "COUNTY" ...
     $ state_ansi           : chr  "19" "19" "19" "19" ...
     $ unit_desc            : chr  "ACRES" "ACRES" "ACRES" "ACRES" ...
     $ load_time            : chr  "2019-03-21 15:00:18" "2018-02-22 15:08:35" "2017-02-23 15:00:08" "2016-02-18 15:04:50" ...
     $ sector_desc          : chr  "CROPS" "CROPS" "CROPS" "CROPS" ...
     $ state_name           : chr  "IOWA" "IOWA" "IOWA" "IOWA" ...
     $ congr_district_code  : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
     $ state_fips_code      : chr  "19" "19" "19" "19" ...
     $ commodity_desc       : chr  "CORN" "CORN" "CORN" "CORN" ...
     $ asd_desc             : chr  "WEST CENTRAL" "WEST CENTRAL" "WEST CENTRAL" "WEST CENTRAL" ...
     $ source_desc          : chr  "SURVEY" "SURVEY" "SURVEY" "SURVEY" ...
     $ util_practice_desc   : chr  "ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES" "ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES" "ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES" "ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES" ...
     $ reference_period_desc: chr  "YEAR" "YEAR" "YEAR" "YEAR" ...
     $ watershed_code       : chr  "00000000" "00000000" "00000000" "00000000" ...
     $ CV (%)               : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
     $ county_ansi          : chr  "165" "165" "165" "165" ...
     $ group_desc           : chr  "FIELD CROPS" "FIELD CROPS" "FIELD CROPS" "FIELD CROPS" ...
     $ zip_5                : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
     $ domaincat_desc       : chr  "NOT SPECIFIED" "NOT SPECIFIED" "NOT SPECIFIED" "NOT SPECIFIED" ...
     $ Value                : num  172500 172000 180000 175000 182000 ...
     $ region_desc          : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
     $ domain_desc          : chr  "TOTAL" "TOTAL" "TOTAL" "TOTAL" ...
     $ county_name          : chr  "SHELBY" "SHELBY" "SHELBY" "SHELBY" ...
     $ short_desc           : chr  "CORN - ACRES PLANTED" "CORN - ACRES PLANTED" "CORN - ACRES PLANTED" "CORN - ACRES PLANTED" ...
     $ begin_code           : chr  "00" "00" "00" "00" ...
     $ county_code          : chr  "165" "165" "165" "165" ...
     $ statisticcat_desc    : chr  "AREA PLANTED" "AREA PLANTED" "AREA PLANTED" "AREA PLANTED" ...
     $ freq_desc            : chr  "ANNUAL" "ANNUAL" "ANNUAL" "ANNUAL" ...
     $ week_ending          : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
     $ location_desc        : chr  "IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY" "IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY" "IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY" "IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY" ...
     $ class_desc           : chr  "ALL CLASSES" "ALL CLASSES" "ALL CLASSES" "ALL CLASSES" ...
     $ end_code             : chr  "00" "00" "00" "00" ...
     $ country_code         : chr  "9000" "9000" "9000" "9000" ...
     $ watershed_desc       : chr  "" "" "" "" ...
     $ year                 : int  2018 2017 2016 2015 2014 2013 2012 2011 2010 2009 ...
     $ state_alpha          : chr  "IA" "IA" "IA" "IA" ...
     $ prodn_practice_desc  : chr  "ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES" "ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES" "ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES" "ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES" ...
     $ asd_code             : chr  "40" "40" "40" "40" ...
     $ OBS                  :'data.frame':  93 obs. of  1 variable:
      ..$ z: num  9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
    head(SB)
    country_name agg_level_desc state_ansi unit_desc           load_time sector_desc state_name
    1 UNITED STATES         COUNTY         19     ACRES 2019-03-21 15:00:18       CROPS       IOWA
    2 UNITED STATES         COUNTY         19     ACRES 2018-02-22 15:08:35       CROPS       IOWA
    3 UNITED STATES         COUNTY         19     ACRES 2017-02-23 15:00:08       CROPS       IOWA
    4 UNITED STATES         COUNTY         19     ACRES 2016-02-18 15:04:50       CROPS       IOWA
    5 UNITED STATES         COUNTY         19     ACRES 2015-02-19 15:38:52       CROPS       IOWA
    6 UNITED STATES         COUNTY         19     ACRES 2015-02-19 15:38:52       CROPS       IOWA
      congr_district_code state_fips_code commodity_desc     asd_desc source_desc        util_practice_desc
    1                                  19           CORN WEST CENTRAL      SURVEY ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES
    2                                  19           CORN WEST CENTRAL      SURVEY ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES
    3                                  19           CORN WEST CENTRAL      SURVEY ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES
    4                                  19           CORN WEST CENTRAL      SURVEY ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES
    5                                  19           CORN WEST CENTRAL      SURVEY ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES
    6                                  19           CORN WEST CENTRAL      SURVEY ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES
      reference_period_desc watershed_code CV (%) county_ansi  group_desc zip_5 domaincat_desc  Value region_desc
    1                  YEAR       00000000                165 FIELD CROPS        NOT SPECIFIED 172500            
    2                  YEAR       00000000                165 FIELD CROPS        NOT SPECIFIED 172000            
    3                  YEAR       00000000                165 FIELD CROPS        NOT SPECIFIED 180000            
    4                  YEAR       00000000                165 FIELD CROPS        NOT SPECIFIED 175000            
    5                  YEAR       00000000                165 FIELD CROPS        NOT SPECIFIED 182000            
    6                  YEAR       00000000                165 FIELD CROPS        NOT SPECIFIED 186500            
      domain_desc county_name           short_desc begin_code county_code statisticcat_desc freq_desc week_ending
    1       TOTAL      SHELBY CORN - ACRES PLANTED         00         165      AREA PLANTED    ANNUAL            
    2       TOTAL      SHELBY CORN - ACRES PLANTED         00         165      AREA PLANTED    ANNUAL            
    3       TOTAL      SHELBY CORN - ACRES PLANTED         00         165      AREA PLANTED    ANNUAL            
    4       TOTAL      SHELBY CORN - ACRES PLANTED         00         165      AREA PLANTED    ANNUAL            
    5       TOTAL      SHELBY CORN - ACRES PLANTED         00         165      AREA PLANTED    ANNUAL            
    6       TOTAL      SHELBY CORN - ACRES PLANTED         00         165      AREA PLANTED    ANNUAL            
                   location_desc  class_desc end_code country_code watershed_desc year state_alpha
    1 IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY ALL CLASSES       00         9000                2018          IA
    2 IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY ALL CLASSES       00         9000                2017          IA
    3 IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY ALL CLASSES       00         9000                2016          IA
    4 IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY ALL CLASSES       00         9000                2015          IA
    5 IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY ALL CLASSES       00         9000                2014          IA
    6 IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY ALL CLASSES       00         9000                2013          IA
           prodn_practice_desc asd_code z
    1 ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES       40 9
    2 ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES       40 9
    3 ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES       40 9
    4 ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES       40 9
    5 ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES       40 9
    6 ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES       40 9

    dput(head(SB))
structure(list(country_name = c("UNITED STATES", "UNITED STATES", 
"UNITED STATES", "UNITED STATES", "UNITED STATES", "UNITED STATES"
), agg_level_desc = c("COUNTY", "COUNTY", "COUNTY", "COUNTY", 
"COUNTY", "COUNTY"), state_ansi = c("19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
"19"), unit_desc = c("ACRES", "ACRES", "ACRES", "ACRES", "ACRES", 
"ACRES"), load_time = c("2019-03-21 15:00:18", "2018-02-22 15:08:35", 
"2017-02-23 15:00:08", "2016-02-18 15:04:50", "2015-02-19 15:38:52", 
"2015-02-19 15:38:52"), sector_desc = c("CROPS", "CROPS", "CROPS", 
"CROPS", "CROPS", "CROPS"), state_name = c("IOWA", "IOWA", "IOWA", 
"IOWA", "IOWA", "IOWA"), congr_district_code = c("", "", "", 
"", "", ""), state_fips_code = c("19", "19", "19", "19", "19", 
"19"), commodity_desc = c("CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", "CORN", 
"CORN"), asd_desc = c("WEST CENTRAL", "WEST CENTRAL", "WEST CENTRAL", 
"WEST CENTRAL", "WEST CENTRAL", "WEST CENTRAL"), source_desc = c("SURVEY", 
"SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY", "SURVEY"), util_practice_desc = c("ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES", 
"ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES", "ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES", "ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES", 
"ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES", "ALL UTILIZATION PRACTICES"), reference_period_desc = c("YEAR", 
"YEAR", "YEAR", "YEAR", "YEAR", "YEAR"), watershed_code = c("00000000", 
"00000000", "00000000", "00000000", "00000000", "00000000"), 
    `CV (%)` = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), county_ansi = c("165", 
    "165", "165", "165", "165", "165"), group_desc = c("FIELD CROPS", 
    "FIELD CROPS", "FIELD CROPS", "FIELD CROPS", "FIELD CROPS", 
    "FIELD CROPS"), zip_5 = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), domaincat_desc = c("NOT SPECIFIED", 
    "NOT SPECIFIED", "NOT SPECIFIED", "NOT SPECIFIED", "NOT SPECIFIED", 
    "NOT SPECIFIED"), Value = c(172500, 172000, 180000, 175000, 
    182000, 186500), region_desc = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), 
    domain_desc = c("TOTAL", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", "TOTAL", 
    "TOTAL"), county_name = c("SHELBY", "SHELBY", "SHELBY", "SHELBY", 
    "SHELBY", "SHELBY"), short_desc = c("CORN - ACRES PLANTED", 
    "CORN - ACRES PLANTED", "CORN - ACRES PLANTED", "CORN - ACRES PLANTED", 
    "CORN - ACRES PLANTED", "CORN - ACRES PLANTED"), begin_code = c("00", 
    "00", "00", "00", "00", "00"), county_code = c("165", "165", 
    "165", "165", "165", "165"), statisticcat_desc = c("AREA PLANTED", 
    "AREA PLANTED", "AREA PLANTED", "AREA PLANTED", "AREA PLANTED", 
    "AREA PLANTED"), freq_desc = c("ANNUAL", "ANNUAL", "ANNUAL", 
    "ANNUAL", "ANNUAL", "ANNUAL"), week_ending = c("", "", "", 
    "", "", ""), location_desc = c("IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY", 
    "IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY", "IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY", 
    "IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY", "IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY", 
    "IOWA, WEST CENTRAL, SHELBY"), class_desc = c("ALL CLASSES", 
    "ALL CLASSES", "ALL CLASSES", "ALL CLASSES", "ALL CLASSES", 
    "ALL CLASSES"), end_code = c("00", "00", "00", "00", "00", 
    "00"), country_code = c("9000", "9000", "9000", "9000", "9000", 
    "9000"), watershed_desc = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), year = 2018:2013, 
    state_alpha = c("IA", "IA", "IA", "IA", "IA", "IA"), prodn_practice_desc = c("ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES", 
    "ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES", "ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES", "ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES", 
    "ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES", "ALL PRODUCTION PRACTICES"), 
    asd_code = c("40", "40", "40", "40", "40", "40"), OBS = structure(list(
        z = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I think there may be a better way to bind these two data frames, look into the merge funciton or the *_join functions from the `dplyr` package.

Comment: You have a malformed dataframe where one of it's columns is another list. DON'T DO THAT.

Comment: @42- could you help more than that? I'm here to learn and get help not drive-by commented without further explanation.

Comment: The OBS "column" is not a vector; it's another dataframe inside the main dataframe. This ist code that converts it into a less pathological object. `SB$OBS <- SB$OBS$z` And I'm not answering the main question because I get rather annoyed at people who insult me when I offered useful advice.

Comment: @42- Well thank you for help (SB$OBS <- SB$OBS$z) converted it for me and the plot works now.  and I hope your day gets better.